# SQLAlchemy: a better way for update with declarative?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, declarative

Let's say I have a user table in declarative mode:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(u'id', Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(u'name', String(50))
```

When I know user's id without object loaded into session, I update such user like this:

```
ex = update(User.__table__).where(User.id==123).values(name=u"Bob Marley")
Session.execute(ex)
```

I dislike using `User.__table__`, should I stop worrying with that?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: update http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There's also some update capability at the ORM level. It doesn't handle any tricky cases yet but for the trivial case of single row update (or bulk update) it works fine. It even goes over any already loaded objects and applies the update on them also. You can use it like this:

```
session.query(User).filter_by(id=123).update({"name": u"Bob Marley"})
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the user assigned variable names for the columns - If name were declared user_name = Column("name", String(50)), this would fail b/c the actual name of the column is required. Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Shouldn't that be either `.get(123)` or `.filter_by(id == 123)` ?

Comment: @Brendan `filter` and `filter_by` are different methods. The former takes an expression as an argument while the latter takes keyword arguments.

Comment: @Kira: Late response, but I'll add it in case anyone else needs it.
session.query(User).filter_by(id=123).update({User.name: "Bob Marley"})

Comment: Would `session.query(User).with_for_update().filter_by(id=123).update({"name": u"Bob Marley"})` be better to ensure atomicity?

Comment: @RichardLaw No, `FOR UPDATE` is not a part of an `UPDATE` statement and SQLA simply ignores the `with_for_update()`.

Comment: So you can't update a single row but you can update a list of rows? Is that why `.get().update()` doesn't work while the filter method does? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 20):

You're working on *clause* level here, not on model/entity/object level. Clause level is lower than mapped objects. And yes, something have to be done to convert one terms into others.

You could also stay on object level and do:

```
session = Session()
u = session.query(User).get(123)
u.name = u"Bob Marley"
session.commit()
```

but it will be significantly slower since it leads to the mapped object construction. And I'm not sure that it is more readable.

In the example your provided I see the most natural and “right” solution. I would not worry about little `__table__` magic.

Answer (score 4):

Similar functionality is available via the `update()` method on Table object.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__   = 'user'
    id = Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(50))

stmt = User.__table__.update().where(User.id==5).values(name='user #5')
```

To use `User.__table__` is how its done in SQLAlchemy.