# SqlAlchemy update not working with Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I followed the (two) examples in this question: [SQLAlchemy: a better way for update with declarative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631935/sqlalchemy-a-better-way-for-update-with-declarative)

And I'm finding that a model update does not happen when using sqlite with flask-sqlalchemy on Ubuntu Linux. The very simplest example doesn't work for me:

```
class Task:
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True)
    desc= db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False)
    state= db.Column(db.Boolean)

    # ...

@app.route("/task/<int:id>/update",methods=["POST"])
def toggle_state(id):
    db.session.query(Task).get(id).update({"state":True})
    log.info("state is now: " + str(Task.query.get(id).state))
    # prints "state is now: False"
```

First time using flask/sqlalchemy, so I assume I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 33):

So I tried several different things. Here's what didn't work, and what finally did work:

Didn't work:

```
# this will throw an exception, "AttributeError: 'Task' object has no attribute 'update'"
db.session.query(Task).get(id).update({"state":state})
db.session.commit()

# this was the example in the linked SO thread:
# does nothing
db.session.query(Task).filter_by(id=id).update({"state":state})

#this also does nothing
task = Task.query.filter_by(id=id)
task.state = state
db.session.commit()

#not this either
task = Task.query.get(id)
task.state = state
db.session.commit()
```

Did work:

```
#ok this works:
db.session.query(Task).filter_by(id=id).update({"state":state})
db.session.commit()

#and also this:
task = db.session.query(Task).get(id)
task.state = state
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: For declarative style: `session.query(Task).filter_by(id=id).update({"state":state})`

Comment: can anyone explain why ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, it's soooo weird.

Comment: Yes, I'd also like to know why...

Comment: I had used syntax synchronize_session="fetch" in the update too - thinking that was mandated. But the session.commit() was the bit that worked - maybe there is an auto commit option too on the session. I will add I was using `id.in_()` 
 functionality too and it did the updates in bulk and that was ok after the commit.